# PHP ibsert picture width and height

Tags: php, image

How do I write in width 200px height auto in this code?

```
echo '<img src="'.$image_name 
.'" alt="'.$image_name.'"/> 
'."<br /><br />"; } else { 
continue; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add inline style `width:200px;height:auto;`

Hence, change to

```
echo '<img style="width:200px;height:auto;" src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'"/> '."<br /><br />"; 
} else{ 
continue; } }
```